# how to make node js online video streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, stream, video-streaming

here is my node js code

```
socket.on('stream',()=>{
        let  readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/video.mp4');
        readStream.on('data',(chunk)=>{

           socket.emit('stream-chunk',chunk);
            //res.render("hello");
        });
    });
```

and here is the client side

```
            let chunkArray = [];
            socket.on('stream-chunk', (chunk) => { 
                    chunkArray.push(chunk);
                    //console.log(chunk);
                    //var url = URL.createObjectURL(chunk);
                    //alert(url);
                    $("#video").attr("src",url);

            });
```

so as you can see I just want to get a video file from node server and stream it using buffers.. so far the chunks come as ArrayBuffers to client side. But I have no idea how to make use this incoming chunks to my html5 `<video>` element

here is my client side html tag

```
<video controls type="video/mp4" src="" id="video" width="300" height="300"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my full ground-up example implementation using NodeJS and FFmpeg to handle HTTP Live Streams HLS + m3u8 i.e. VOD. Check it

https://github.com/pluginfactory/HLS-transcoding-nodejs

Answer (score 3):

Just use HTTP straight-up.  No need to use web sockets for one-way communication.

Use Express to serve that file statically.  Then in your video tag, `src="path/video.mp4"`.

Comment: when a huge video file comes would that be ok? I want to make it so that it will stream like youtube

Comment: @THEWOLF Yes, in fact it will be better than what you're doing now.  When you stream it over HTTP, congestion control is handled a couple of different ways.  The most straightforward part is through regular TCP congestion control.  When the browser doesn't want to buffer any more data, it shuts the window.  Eventually it can disconnect if it chooses, or it can open the window again to accept more data.  Browsers like Chrome actually only request fragments of a file at a time, via ranged requests.  Express handles all of that for you under the hood.

Comment: oh ok then. I just want the most optimal solution for this. then I will just use the path right? When a user request a video I will just send the path string and append it to video src right ?